# Simple HTTP server application for Windows that can be launched on-demand?

Tags: apache, ant, jetty, httpserver

I need a simple HTTP server application that meets the following criteria:

1. It must run on Windows.
2. It must *NOT* require **new** Windows installations of any sort: programs, frameworks, services, etc.
3. It can be run with Java (e.g. JARs) or .NET as those frameworks are already installed globally on the servers.
4. It must be able to be started **and** stopped by an Ant build (and/or from command line) on demand.
5. It must be able to host on a port specified at runtime (i.e. *not* in a config file).
6. It must only be able to host basic static content (JavaScript, CSS, Images, HTML) from a root directory specified at runtime (i.e. *not* in a config file).
7. Must not require a huge distribution folder, e.g. the full Jetty distribution is approximately 40 MB... way too big! Under 1 MB would be preferred.
8. It does *NOT* need to support HTTPS (SSL).
9. It does *NOT* need to integrate with any IDEs.
10. It does *NOT* need to host any "web applications", e.g. EARs, WARs, JARs, etc.

Any recommendations?  I will also need a guide/tutorial explanation for setting them up, especially if they are Java-based as I have very little background in Java (and honestly not *that* much background in Ant, either).

Thanks!

Comment: Regarding Jetty, if it's just for static content, you should be able to remove a number of jars (more so if you're willing to embed Jetty within your small application to do this).

Comment: Might find more information in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050851/best-lightweight-web-server-only-static-content-for-windows

Comment: @Bruno Care to comment further on my other question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555868/how-to-start-an-aggregate-jetty-server-jar-from-ant

Comment: @Hexxagonal: I did see that one, though most don't meet my requirements either due to needing installation or not being dynamically configurable. There are a few valid candidates there, though.

Answer (score 3):

I would recomment onehttpd - https://code.google.com/p/onehttpd/

It's one 62.5K executable. You can run it as easy as `onehttpd.exe -p 80 c:\var\www`.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some lightweight web servers that appear to work on Windows and have minimal dependencies:

Resin: http://www.caucho.com/resin-web-server/ <-- Requires java

Hiawatha: http://www.hiawatha-webserver.org/

Cherokee: http://www.cherokee-project.com/doc/

Answer (score 1):

If you need a very light HTTP server, you can use NanoHTTPD. It is distributed as a tiny Jar (an unique class if I recall well).

Also, it is very easy to modify according to your needs (and BSD licensed).

http://elonen.iki.fi/code/nanohttpd/