# Minimum set of files needed from Jetty to serve static content?

Tags: java, windows, ant, jetty, embedded-jetty

## Background

**Disclaimer:** I have *very* little experience with Java.

We previously used a wrapped version of Jetty 6 for on-demand static content (JS, CSS, images, HTML) during our Ant build so we can run unit tests with PhantomJS against an HTTP-hosted environment.

However, Jetty is now on version 8.1.3 and we no longer need that wrapping (which solves a different problem which is now moot), so I wanted to update to just using Jetty 8.1.3 directly.

First I downloaded the whole Jetty distribution, which weighs in at a massive ~40 MB. This works from Ant, using "start.jar"... but I don't really want to be pushing those unnecessary JARs around everywhere.

So then I downloaded the aggregate "jetty-server-8.1.3.v20120416.jar" (latest) from the Maven repo, BUT I can't seem to use that JAR from Ant like I could with "start.jar", e.g. "java -jar jetty-server-8.1.3.v20120416.jar OPTIONS=Server"

The Jetty documentation is both poor and missing (404's). Ugh!

## Actual Question

So, if I go back to using the full distribution of Jetty with "start.jar" instead of the aggregate "jetty-server", **what is the minimum set of files (JARs and configs) from the full Jetty distribution that I need to server basic static content over HTTP?**

...

**Related Question:** [How to start an aggregate jetty-server JAR from Ant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555868/how-to-start-an-aggregate-jetty-server-jar-from-ant)

Comment: P.S. This is **not** a duplicate of the related question [How to start an aggregate jetty-server JAR from Ant?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555868/how-to-start-an-aggregate-jetty-server-jar-from-ant). The actual questions are **different**, they just have the same background information.

Answer (score 1):

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Use_Jetty_with_Ant

if you don't need things like jetty-jmx or jetty-jndi then just trim those

Comment: I know that there is a Jetty Ant task but your answer doesn't help me figure out what my minimum set of required JARs, configs, etc. is.

Comment: that is because that is different for different uses, get it working with what is there and start trimming out what you don't need.  don't need webapps, then remove jetty-webapp, don't need servlets, remove jetty-servlets, don't need websockets then remove jetty-websockets

Comment: but if you don't want to work backwards, start with jetty-util, jetty-io, jetty-http, jetty-server, and probably the servlet-api

Comment: Are there descriptions available of what each one of these packages/JARs does to help me figure out what I need?