# Javascript FileReader()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to load another page from another page using javascript filereader(), how do I specify the parameter of the function according to the div ?

html code :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>

    <div class='try1' onclick="openFile('test1.txt')">Show Test1</div>
    <div class='try2' onclick="openFile('test2.txt')">Show Test2</div>

    <div id='show_content'></div>

<script>
    var openFile = function(event) {
    var input = event;

    var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(){
            var text = reader.result;
            document.getElementById("show_content").innerHTML = (reader.result.substring(0, 200));
        };
    reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
    };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want it so that when :

1) I click div class='try1', it will load a file called 'test1.txt' into div id='show_content',

2) and when I click div class='try2', it will load a file called 'test2.txt' into div id='show_content'.

How do I achieve this ? I know I can use jQuery .load() function, but it turns out that jQuery .load() function need a server and uses xmlhttprequest to load, and I need to do this locally. Please if there's any better solution to achieve this, all answers are greatly appreciated. Thx

Comment: For security reasons, you should not be able to see any local path of the user with javascript, nor to set it. Your best bet is using XMLHttpRequest, whether on a local server, or with firefox browser which seems to accept it on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

you can put an hidden `input` in the page and then invoke `openFile` explicitly;

```
<div id='try1' onclick="openFile('test.txt')">show try 1</div>
<div id="show_content"></div>
<input type="file" id="fileElem"  accept="text/plain" style="display:none" onchange="openFile(event)">
```

you only need to add a event listener to your `div`:

```
var try1 = document.getElementById("try1"),
fileElem = document.getElementById("fileElem");

try1.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    if (fileElem) {
        fileElem.click();
    }
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent navigation to "#"
}, false);
```

and finally:

```
var openFile = function (event) {
    var input = event.target;

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function () {
        var text = reader.result;
        var content = document.getElementById("show_content");
        content.innerHTML = reader.result.substring(0, 200);
    };
    reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
};
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do this with jquery, I have done this locally without any server.

for the 1st one try this:

```
$(".try1").click(function () {
    $("#show_content").load("text1.txt", function (responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr) {
        if (statusTxt == "success")
        {
            //alert("External content loaded successfully!");
        }

        if (statusTxt == "error")
        {
            //alert("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
        }
    });
});
```

and for the second one:

```
$(".try2").click(function () {
        $("#show_content").load("text2.txt", function (responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr) {
            if (statusTxt == "success")
            {
                //alert("External content loaded successfully!");
            }

            if (statusTxt == "error")
            {
                //alert("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: I copied and paste your exact code and deleted my script, it alerted error :javascript alert

Error: 0; NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'file:///C:/Users/HP/Desktop/homepage/text1.txt'.

Comment: Then I tried moving the whole folder to xampp htdocs, as expected, it works fine. What is the reason for this ? I could not find any clue regarding this matter in the internet

Comment: you are right AJAX doesn't support 'file://' you should set up a 'http://' server to host your files.

Comment: if you want creat a 'http://' server: this would help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050851/best-lightweight-web-server-only-static-content-for-windows

Comment: yup, thats why im trying to use javascript FileReader api, I managed to read the files using <input type='file' accept='text/*' onchange='openFile(event)'> and var input = event.target, then create the filereader() object, but now if I want to use the div as the parameter, how do I achieve this ?