# Vue: header is not refreshed right away. But localStorage is changed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

When I login using a form this happens:

1. loggedIn value in localStorage is changed to "true"
2. Router pushes to /home
3. Header doesn't change and still shows Login/Signup buttons

I need it to be

1. loggedIn value in localStorage is changed to "true"
2. Router pushes to /home
3. Header changes and a picture

**Header.vue**:

```html
      <div class="flex flex-wrap items-center justify-end ">
        <HeaderItem v-if="!isLoggedIn"
            class="pl-10" text = "Login" link="/login"/>
        <HeaderItem v-if="!isLoggedIn" class="pl-10"
                    text = "Signup" link="/signup"/>

        <div v-if="isLoggedIn">
          <UserHeader/>
        </div>
      </div>
```

```js
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {HeaderItem, UserHeader},
  data() {
    return {
      homeLink: "/home"
    }
  },
  created: {
    isLoggedIn() {
      console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("loggedIn")) === "true");

      if (localStorage.getItem("loggedIn") === "true")  {
        console.log("STORAGE LOGGED IN TRUE");
      }
      else  {
        console.log("STORAGE LOGGED IN FALSE");
      }

      return localStorage.getItem("loggedIn") === "true";
    }
  }
}
```

It only prints the correct message and changes header after I press Ctrl+Shift+R. But the localStorage has the correct `loggedIn` value right away. How do I fix it?

**EDIT**:

I also tried this:

```html
  <div class="flex flex-wrap items-center justify-end ">
        <HeaderItem v-if="!loggedIn"
            class="pl-10" text = "Login" link="/login"/>
        <HeaderItem v-if="!loggedIn" class="pl-10"
                    text = "Signup" link="/signup"/>

        <div v-if="loggedIn">
          <UserHeader/>
        </div>
      </div>
```

```js
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {HeaderItem, UserHeader},
  data() {
    return {
      homeLink: "/home",
     // loggedIn: false
    }
  },
  computed: {
    loggedIn() {
      return localStorage.getItem("loggedIn") === "true";
    },
...
```

It has the same results: the header only changes after the page refresh (Ctrl+Shift+R).

**EDIT**:

I **can't** set `localStorage.loggedIn` inside `Header`! It is set in **LoginForm.vue**, completely different component

Comment: $("#header").load("../pages/header.html");

Comment: *doesn't work* - please provide *some* diagnostic checks.  Is there an error in the console `.load is not a function` or `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.  Is there an error in network tab:  `404 header.html not found`  See https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/

Comment: That (most likely) means you're opening the `.html` file locally from your computer, eg double-clicking on your desktop.  Some js actions (eg ajax) are blocked giving that message when opening an html page this way.  You need to "run" your page from a server - eg see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050851/best-lightweight-web-server-only-static-content-for-windows

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Local storage isn't reactive so VueJS can't detect changes to it. As a result, your computed property is unable to track changes to it

The reason it works on a reload is that computed methods will always run at least once to generate the initial value.

You need to tie the updating of local storage with a reactive variable like a boolean.

Each time you access your local storage object, check the storage value and set a boolean in VueJS - something like `isLoggedIn` and use that instead of your computed method.

You can either use Vuex and commits, or simply set the state of the header component.

For example, when your component is created you can set `isLoggedIn` to true or false depending on if the local storage key is present.

Similarly, you can also set `isLoggedIn` to true when a user logs in (In the same method you set your local storage key) and to false when a user logs out.

Consider the following example:

**Header.vue**

```
  <div class="flex flex-wrap items-center justify-end ">
    <HeaderItem v-if="!isLoggedIn"
        class="pl-10" text = "Login" link="/login"/>
    <HeaderItem v-if="!isLoggedIn" class="pl-10"
                text = "Signup" link="/signup"/>

    <div v-if="isLoggedIn">
      <UserHeader/>
    </div>
  </div>

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {HeaderItem, UserHeader},
  data() {
    return {
      homeLink: "/home",
      isLoggedIn: false,
    }
  },
  computed: {
      isLoggedIn() {
          return this.$store.state.isLoggedIn;
      }
  },
}
```

**And then in any other component**

```
  created() {
      if (localStorage.getItem("loggedIn") === "true")  {
          this.$store.commit('SET_LOGGED_IN', true);
      }
  },
  methods: {
       login() {
           localStorage.setItem('loggedIn', 'true');
           this.$store.commit('SET_LOGGED_IN', true); 
       }
  }
```

For the above example, you have a Vuex store with a boolean state called `isLoggedIn`. You then commit a mutation called `SET_LOGGED_IN` that sets the state of `isLoggedIn` to true or false.

Using a computed property in any component, you can easily access the value of `isLoggedIn` and reactively respond to changes in it.

Every time you update or read from the local storage, you must also update a variable in VueJS. That variable is what is reactive.

Comment: Could you please show some code of how would I do that? Where would that variable go? I know how to use vuex's store, but the store is wiped after a page reload...

Comment: Exactly why you're using local storage for the key. Let me update the code give me a couple minutes

Comment: I asked around and everyone uses localStorage for user token.

Comment: What about this one? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event

Comment: You can do that too. What you need to do is at the same time as when ytou update local storage, you also update your variable :)

Comment: @parsecer for vue.js, you don't need storage_event, the best practice is Bus Event of vue.js. I have updated my code below, give it a try.

Comment: I **can't** set `localStorage.loggedIn` inside `Header`! It is set in **LoginForm.vue**, completely different component

Comment: Header **only** has access to vuex or localstorage

Comment: That is fine. You just need to use Vuex instead. Inside your LoginForm.vue, you need need to commit to Vuex to set a boolean each time you change local storage. When you login, commit something. When you log out, commit something, etc. Then in your Header you need to just access the Vuex  state instead of the isLoggedIn local variable

Comment: @parsecer I have updated my example to demonstrate with Vuex instead

Answer (score 0):

If you want your functions to be reactive on the same component, then create a variable and set its value where you set the localStorage loggedIn value.

**This is just an example code:**

```
<template>
  <div class="flex flex-wrap items-center justify-end ">
    <h3>{{ isLoggedIn }}</h3>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        loggedIn: false
      }
    },
    created () {
      // added 3 seconds gap to make the value true and check reactivity
      setTimeout(() => this.onSignIn(), 3000)
    },
    computed: {
      
      isLoggedIn() {
        if (localStorage.getItem('loggedIn')) return localStorage.getItem("loggedIn") === "true";
        return this.loggedIn
      }
    },
    methods: {
      onSignIn () {
        this.loggedIn = true
        localStorage.setItem('loggedIn', true)
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

**Update 2:**

After understanding your situation from a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67235842/vue-header-doesnt-get-renewed-after-login-logout-but-localstorage-is-changed/67235909#67235909) similar to this that you asked. Here is the code, that will help you in your case wherein `LoginForm.vue` you are setting localStorage value and you want to use that value in your `App.vue` and pass it to `Header.vue`.
For such case, I used the [Bus Event](https://dev.to/ihavecoke/eventbus-on-vue-js-3edo) in order to communicate between the component which might be far on the parent to access, such as App.vue.

**event-bus.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
const EventBus = new Vue();
export default EventBus;
```

**LoginForm.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="home-page">
    <button type="submit" @click="onSignIn()">Login</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import EventBus from '../event-bus';
  export default {
    methods: {
      onSignIn () {
        localStorage.setItem('loggedIn', true)
        EventBus.$emit('OnLogin', true)
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Header :isLoggedIn="isLoggedIn"/>
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import Header from './components/Header'
import EventBus from './event-bus';
export default {
  components: {
    Header
  },
  data() {
    return {
      loggedIn: false
    }
  },
  computed: {
    isLoggedIn() {
      if (localStorage.getItem('loggedIn')) return localStorage.getItem("loggedIn") === "true";
      return this.loggedIn
    }
  },
  created () {
    EventBus.$on('OnLogin', (isLogin) => {
      this.loggedIn = isLogin
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

**Header.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="flex flex-wrap items-center justify-end ">
    <HeaderItem v-if="!isLoggedIn"
        class="pl-10" text = "Login" link="/login"/>
    <HeaderItem v-if="!isLoggedIn" class="pl-10"
                text = "Signup" link="/signup"/>

    <div v-if="isLoggedIn">
      <UserHeader/>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HeaderItem from './HeaderItem'
import UserHeader from './UserHeader'
  export default {
    components: {HeaderItem, UserHeader},
    props: ['isLoggedIn']
  }
</script>
```