# Vue: header doesn't get renewed after login/logout but localStorage is changed

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

When I login using a form this happens:

1. loggedIn value in localStorage is changed to "true"
2. Router pushes to /home
3. Header doesn't change and still shows Login/Signup buttons

I need it to be

1. loggedIn value in localStorage is changed to "true"
2. Router pushes to /home
3. Header changes and a picture

**Header.vue**:

```html
      <div class="flex flex-wrap items-center justify-end ">
        <HeaderItem v-if="!isLoggedIn"
            class="pl-10" text = "Login" link="/login"/>
        <HeaderItem v-if="!isLoggedIn" class="pl-10"
                    text = "Signup" link="/signup"/>

        <div v-if="isLoggedIn">
          <UserHeader/>
        </div>
      </div>
```

```js
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {HeaderItem, UserHeader},
  data() {
    return {
      homeLink: "/home"
    }
  },
  created: {
    isLoggedIn() {
      console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("loggedIn")) === "true");

      if (localStorage.getItem("loggedIn") === "true")  {
        console.log("STORAGE LOGGED IN TRUE");
      }
      else  {
        console.log("STORAGE LOGGED IN FALSE");
      }

      return localStorage.getItem("loggedIn") === "true";
    }
  }
}
```

It only prints the correct message and changes header after I press Ctrl+Shift+R. But the localStorage has the correct `loggedIn` value right away. How do I fix it?

**EDIT**:

I also tried this:

```html
  <div class="flex flex-wrap items-center justify-end ">
        <HeaderItem v-if="!loggedIn"
            class="pl-10" text = "Login" link="/login"/>
        <HeaderItem v-if="!loggedIn" class="pl-10"
                    text = "Signup" link="/signup"/>

        <div v-if="loggedIn">
          <UserHeader/>
        </div>
      </div>
```

```js
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {HeaderItem, UserHeader},
  data() {
    return {
      homeLink: "/home",
     // loggedIn: false
    }
  },
  computed: {
    loggedIn() {
      return localStorage.getItem("loggedIn") === "true";
    },
...
```

It has the same results: the header only changes after the page refresh (Ctrl+Shift+R).

Comment: Could you share where are you setting the localStorage loggedIn item and in sub component or parent component where are you checking isLoggedIn?

Answer (score 3):

The `created` is a lifecycle or hook of vue.js, inside it whatever functions/methods you define, is not available to run.

**As in your case, you want to use as a variable, then use `computed` property.**

Here is the fix version of your code:

```
computed: {
      isLoggedIn() {
        console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("loggedIn")) === "true");

        if (localStorage.getItem("loggedIn") === "true")  {
          console.log("STORAGE LOGGED IN TRUE");
        }
        else  {
          console.log("STORAGE LOGGED IN FALSE");
        }

        return localStorage.getItem("loggedIn") === "true";
      }
    },
```

**Updated:**

If you want your functions to be reactive on the same component, then create a variable and set its value where you set the localStorage loggedIn value.

**This is just an example code:**

```
<template>
  <div class="flex flex-wrap items-center justify-end ">
    <h3>{{ isLoggedIn }}</h3>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        loggedIn: false
      }
    },
    created () {
      // added 3 seconds gap to make the value true and check reactivity
      setTimeout(() => this.onSignIn(), 3000)
    },
    computed: {
      
      isLoggedIn() {
        if (localStorage.getItem('loggedIn')) return localStorage.getItem("loggedIn") === "true";
        return this.loggedIn
      }
    },
    methods: {
      onSignIn () {
        this.loggedIn = true
        localStorage.setItem('loggedIn', true)
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

**Update 2 as per your situation:**

After understanding your situation, here is the code, that will help you. I used the Bus Event in order to communicate between the component which might be far on the parent to access, such as App.vue.

**event-bus.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
const EventBus = new Vue();
export default EventBus;
```

**LoginForm.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="home-page">
    <button type="submit" @click="onSignIn()">Login</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import EventBus from '../event-bus';
  export default {
    methods: {
      onSignIn () {
        localStorage.setItem('loggedIn', true)
        EventBus.$emit('OnLogin', true)
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Header :userLoggedIn="isLoggedIn"/>
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import Header from './components/Header'
import EventBus from './event-bus';
export default {
  components: {
    Header
  },
  data() {
    return {
      isLoggedIn: false
    }
  },
  created () {
    EventBus.$on('OnLogin', (isLogin) => {
      this.isLoggedIn = isLogin
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

**Header.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h2>{{ userLoggedIn }}</h2>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: ['userLoggedIn']
  }
</script>
```

Comment: The issue is also compounded by the fact that `localStorage` objects are not reactive.

Comment: @parsecer if you want it to be reactive on that same component, `create one variable` into `data` and update that...and for other pages, use the` localStorage` variable.

Comment: @parsecer once you refresh the page, the above code will work, but without refreshing the page if you want, then you'll need one variable to use for checking this thing.

Comment: `create one variable into data and update that...and for other pages, use the` localStorage` variable' could you show the code please?

Comment: @RiyazKhan I need the header to get changed right away. So when the router pishes to /home the page there would have the updated header..

Comment: @parsecer do one thing, use the computed property, check the above code. And note, this is not reactive until you refresh the page.

Comment: @RiyazKhan I **need** it to be **reactive**. That's the point of the question

Comment: @parsecer one question, your header and `loggedIn localStorage` setup on the same component?

Comment: What do you mean? Header uses `loggedIn` in `localStorage`. Login form changes `loggedIn` in `localStorage`

Comment: @parsecer I had made the mistake, by putting signIn method inside computed, other than that, all are fines. now it's fixed.

Comment: I can't use `onSignIn` method. My login form component is **independent** from Header. I **can't** **edit** `loggedIn` in `computed` (unexpected side effects error, see post EDIT). I can **only** take `loggedIn` value from `localStorage`

Comment: @parsecer, why are you setting loggedIn variable into computed. it should be set where you are setting localStorage variable.

Comment: @RiyazKhan I'm not sure what you mean. I think my question is pretty clear... I added some more code that I've tried

Comment: @parsecer brother, the place where you set `localStorage.setItem('loggedIn')`, it's there you need to set your variable 'loggedIn' to make it reactive and pass it as props to sub component `Headers.vue`

Comment: I can't do that. `loggedIn` is changed in `LoginForm.vue` which **is not** a parent of **Header.vue** and therefore **can't** set **Header** props from inside **LoginForm**. The **only** place Header is created is **App.vue**. I tried doing `    <Header :userLoggedIn="localStorage.getItem('user') === 'true'"/>` inside **App.vue** but got an error: `Cannot read property 'getItem' of undefined`

Comment: Maybe someone else knows the answer. Thanks for the help

Comment: @parsecer That's what I was wanted to know, about LoginForm and App.vue where your header exists. Based on this, I have edited my solution. check the section `update 2`