# What is the best alternative to HTML Help files

Tags: windows, chm, helpfile

I want to add help files to my windows app. I have been using HTML HELP (chm) files for a long time, but I have seen that it has a lot of security issues. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: Everybody and their brother are delivering help through a web server these days.  If it needs to be local then [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050851/best-lightweight-web-server-only-static-content-for-windows)

Comment: Microsoft promised a new help format but that never happened. As long as you don't host external IFRAMEs and make sure external links open in a real browser there is no security issue with local chm files.